# jQuery UI: Making "file" field in a dialog box part of a form on the main page

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-ui, file-upload, jquery-ui-dialog

I have an application I am writing with a GMail type checkmark selection list. I want to be able to open a Jquery UI dialog and accept a file via a "file" input. The problem is, jQuery moves the dialog box to just before the closing body tag which takes it outside of my form.

Any suggestions on how I could do this? I guess at the end of the road I could set hidden fields for all the checkmarks and have a second form as part of the dialog. Any simpler way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("div").dialog({...}).parent().appendTo("form:first");
```

Answer (score 0):

A dialog box should not be used in context of a form in a separate area. Why don't you use put the file input on the original form? It will be difficult to validate 2 "different" forms if they are not in the same views.

Comment: I am going the dialog route because a I have a few different action options. I want the interface to be clean and a dialog seems more direct than sliding a div or the like.